# How to change the tool tip background color, tooltip displays in td

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i have a  it shows the tootltip while mouse over, now i would like to change the background color of the tooltip.
is there any way of using CSS or JQuery or using class attribute

```
<td title="#487105 CLASSIC LOOSE RD124473 ENGINEERED 2X1-" class="tooltip" rowspan="10" style="white-space:nowrap;">
```

[image]

Comment: Plz put some efforts beofre asking! And how us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would love to see this link for customizing tooltip in jqueryUi:

https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style

Hope this may help you.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try Implementing this in your td:

```
<table border="2px">
   <tr>
     <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
       title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on bottom"
       class="red-tooltip">Tooltip on bottom
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

You could refer this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ckxSs/585/

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use jQuery Plugin or pure css based customised tooltip.

one of the way is below mentioned.

**Include**

jQuery 

 **Inside td keep like this**
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
       title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on bottom"
       class="red-tooltip">#487105 CLASSIC LOOSE RD124473 ENGINEERED 2X1-</a> 
**CSS**

.red-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {background-color: #f00;}

**JS**

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").tooltip();
});
```

View Example - http://jsfiddle.net/ckxSs/16/

Comment: here title is my dynamic data that comes from C# code behind. cannot append all those items

Comment: Same way call the data in anchor tag of just in any lable instead of title.