# How to change tool-tip text color

Tags: css, html

I have a problem with tool-tip.

How to change the  color of series background and series text color to red and blue respectively.

[image]

Comment: are you using twitter bootstrap ?

Comment: it would help if you included some code (it would help even more if you included something like a jsfiddle example)

Comment: .tipsy-inner {
    background-color: red;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 5px 8px 4px;
    text-align: center;
} this is the css, I am using

Answer (score 0):

This would make the background color red and the text blue

```
.tipsy-inner {
    background-color: red;
    color: blue;
}
```

To get rid of the white background - the element that contains the text has a background color set on it which needs to be removed or overwritten. if it's a span I would target it by class or id so as not to interfere with other spans if any. This would target it if it was a span:

```
.tipsy-inner span {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

If you don't know what it is try the selector

```
.tipsy-inner *
```

A bit of a blunt instrument approach when not knowing what the DOM structure is.

Comment: First of all thank for your replay. Still my problem was not solved. text color also not changing. If we remove text back ground color white that great

Comment: Sounds like you got rid of the background color but the color isn't changing.  That may be due another more specific selector. Again blunt instrument make the rule color: blue !important;

Comment: Might be inline styles then which can only updated via script or configuration. I won't he able to help till I get home - currently on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would love to see this link for customizing tooltip in jqueryUi:

https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style

this looks same problem as :

[How to change the tool tip background color, tooltip displays in td](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764989/how-to-change-the-tool-tip-background-color-tooltip-displays-in-td/29765402#29765402)

Hope this may help you.

Thanks!!

Comment: thanks for replay, with out jquery i want to change the tool-tip text background color

Comment: I think you have to provide some more information as code for me to help you out.